# cartesianToPolar for SVG circle / inverse of polartoCartesian

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geometry

I've seen this function floating around:

```js
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}
```

It works fine for my purposes - determining the absolute X, Y coordinates for the given angle on a circle having centerX, centerY and radius.  It works for 360, 0, 180 — all valid SVG values.

Geometry is not my strong suit, but I have not found, nor am I able to write, a function which takes a similar description of the circle, and X, Y coordinates on its circumference (e.g. as output by `polarToCartesian`), and returns an answer corresponding to `angleInDegrees`, with no fudging.  I am looking for a pair of functions with a 1->1 correspondence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Math.atan2(Y-centerY, X-centerX) * 180 /  Math.PI
```

gives you angle of point X,Y relative to center.

Note that in your formula `(angleInDegrees-90)` causes X/Y exchange (like you count angles from vertical axis). If you need this, add 90 to result.

Also atan2 domain is -Pi..Pi (-180..180). If you need only positive angles, add 360 if result is negative.

Seems you need this result:

```
 (Math.atan2(Y-centerY, X-centerX) * 180 /  Math.PI + 450) % 360
```

Comment: For polarToCartesian of 360, this returns 90.  For polarToCartesian of 45, this returns -45.  For 275, returns -175, etc.

Comment: I added formula,  corrected mistake in Y-centerY